# Why is $|S_{m}-S_{n}|$ a Cauchy sequence in Weierstrass’ M-test?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences, pointwise-convergence

The following is a proof of Weierstrass’ M-test:

> Let $\{v_{n}\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on the interval $[a, b]$, and assume that there is a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_{n}$ of positive numbers such that $|v_{n}(x)| \le M_{n}$ for all $n$. Then
>   series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a, b]$.
>
> Proof: Since $(C([a, b], \mathbb{R}), \rho)$ is complete, we only need to check that the partial sums $s_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} v_{k}(x)$ form a Cauchy sequence. Since the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_{n}$ converges, we know that its partial sums $S_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} M_{k}$ form a Cauchy sequence. Since for all $x \in [a, b]$ and all $m > n$,
>   $$|s_{m}(x) − s_{n}(x)| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}v_{k}(x)| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} |v_{k}(x)| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} M_{k} = |S_{m}-S_{n}|,$$
>
> this implies that $\{s_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

So, while I understand that the partial sums $S_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} M_{k}$ form a Cauchy sequence as a result of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_{n}$, how do we know that $m > n$ are sufficiently large so that $|S_{m}-S_{n}|$ converges and is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: You want to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $m,n$ sufficiently large, such that  for any $x$ $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)|<\epsilon$. You do this by show that $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)| \leq |S_m - S_n|$ and then using the fact that $|S_m - S_n| <\epsilon$ for $n,m$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @rubikscube09: then the $m$ and $n$ in $|S_{m}-S_{n}|$ don't necessarily have to be the same $m$ and $n$ in $|s_{m}(x)-s_{n}(x)|$, correct? But why are the indices the same?

Comment: They are the same, because $|S_m - S_n| < \epsilon$ shows that for the same indices $m,n$ , $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)| \leq |S_m - S_n| < \epsilon$, i.e. there is a correspondence.

Comment: @rubikscube09: So are we working backwards, where it is first assumed that $\sum_{k = n+1}^{m} M_{k} = |S_{m}-S_{n}| < \epsilon$, for $m,n$ sufficiently large? Then, we show that $|s_{m}(x)-s_{n}(x)| \le |S_{m}-S_{n}|$?

Comment: Yes, that is what this proof shows. Our goal is to prove things about $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)|$, and we do that by using things we know/proved about $|S_m - S_n|$.